# Transform each of parameter pack's values based on a boolean criteria

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming

I am trying to solve this problem in C++ TMP where in i need to convert one parameter pack types into another, and then convert back the types and also values. The conversion back part is based on a boolean criteria that whether an `arg in Args...` was transformed or not in the first place.

Basically, i have a pack(`Args...`). First, i transform this (`for each args[i], call a transform function`). It works like this:
For each arg in `Args...`, just create same type in `transformed_args...` unless it is one of following, in that case do following conversions:

| Type In Args... | Type In transformed_Args... |
| --- | --- |
| `SomeClass` | `shared_ptr to SomeClass` |
| `std::vector of SomeClass` | `std::vector of shared_ptr to SomeClass` |

everything else remains the same for ex:
`int` remains `int`
`std::string` remains `std::string`

I achieve this by template specialization, of course
For the next part, i take `transformed_args...`, publish a class and a functor. I receive call back on this functor from(C++generated Python using Pybind, not important though). Relevant bits of that class look like this...

```
template<typename C, typename...transformed_args..., typename... Args>
class SomeTemplateClass
{
    MethodWrapper<C,void, Args...> func;
    //.....
    void operator()(transformed_args... targs)
    {
        //....
        (*func.wrapped_method_inside)(transform_back_magic(targs)...)   // this is want i want to achieve.
        //transform_back_magic(targs)... is a plaeholder for code that checks if type of args[i]... != type of targs[i]... and then calls a tranform_back specialization on it else just return args[i].val
    }
}
```

`targs` are in `transformed_args...` format, but underlying C++ function they are aimed for expects `Args...`

```
template<typename... Args, typename... transformed_args, ........whatever else is needed>
transform_back_magic(....)
{
    if(Args[i].type != transformed_args[i].types)
        tranform_back(targs[i]...);
}
```

the tranform_back function template logic is specialized for different cases and all logic is in place. But how to invoke that based on this boolean criteria is hitting my TMP knowledge limits. I just got started not many weeks ago.

---

Here i am listing down what i have created so far.
First of all this is what i need in pseudo code

```
template<typename C, typename... transformed_args, typename... Args>
class SomeTemplateClass
{
    MethodWrapper<C,void, Args...> func;
    void operator(transformed_args... targs)
    {
        **//In pseudo code, this is what i need**
        Args... params = CreateArgsInstanceFromTransformedArgs(targs);
        (*func.wrapped_method_inside)(params...);
    }
}
```

In my attempt to implement this, so far I have decided on creating a `tuple<Args...>` object by copying data from `targs`(with conversions where ever required)

```
void operator(transformed_args... targs)
{
    //....
    

auto mytup = call1(std::tuple<args...>(), std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>, 
std::make_tuple(targs...), targs...);
    

// mytup can be std::tuple<Args...>(transform_back(1st_targs), transform_back(2nd_targs)....). Once available i can write some more logic to extract Args... from this tuple and pass to(*func.wrapped_method_inside)(....)
    (*func.wrapped_method_inside)(ArgsExtractorFromTuple(mytup)); // this part is not implemented yet, but i think it should be possible. This is not my primary concern at the moment
}

//call1


 template<typename... Args, typename... Targs, std::size_t... N>
    auto call1(std::tuple<Args...> tupA, std::index_sequence<N>..., std::tuple<Targs...> tupT, Targs ..)
{
    auto booltup = tuple_creator<0>(tupA, tupT, nullptr);   // to create a tuple of bools
    auto ret1 = std::make_tuple<Args...>(call2(booltup, targs, N)...); // targs and N are expanded together so that i get indirect access to see the corresponding type in Args...
    return ret1;
}
// tuple_creator is a recursive function template with sole purpose to create a boolean tuple.
// such that std::get<0>(booltup) = true, 
//if tuple_element_t<0,std::tuple<Args...>> and tuple_element_t<0,std::tuple<targs...>> are same types else false

template<size_t I, typename... Targs, typename... Args>
auto tuple_creator(std::tuple<Args...>tupA, std::tuple<Targs...>tupT, std::enable_if_t<I == sizeof...(targs)>*)
{
    return std::make_tuple(std::is_same<std::tuple_element_t<I-1, std::tuple<Targs...>>, std::tuple_element_t<I-1, std::tuple<Args...>>>::value);
}

template<size_t I = 0, typename... Targs, typename... Args>
auto tuple_creator(std::tuple<Args...>tupA, std::tuple<Targs...>tupT, std::enable_if_t<I < sizeof...(targs)>*)
{
    auto ret1 = tuple_creator<I+1>(tupA, tupT, nullptr);
    if(!I)
        return ret1;
    auto ret2 = std::is_same<std::tuple_element_t<I-1, std::tuple<Targs...>>, std::tuple_element_t<I-1, std::tuple<Args...>>>::value;
    return std::tuple_cat(ret1, std::make_tuple(ret2));
}

template<typename TT, typename Tuple>
auto call2(Tuple boolyup, TT t, std::size_t I)
{
    auto ret = transform_back<std::get<I>(booltup)>(t); // error: I is not a compile time constant
    return ret;
}
```

`transform_back` is a template that uses a `bool` template param and `enable_if` based specialization to decide whether transform an argument back or not

below are the transform_back specialization for `std::vector`. Similarly i have others for when `T = Class` etc and so on

```
 template<bool sameTypes, typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<(is_vector<T>::value, is_shared_ptr<typename T::value_type>::value && 
is_class<remove_cvref_t<typename T::value_type_element_type>>::value 
&& sameTypes), T>
    transform_back(T val)       // it was never transfoemd in first place, return as is
    {
        return val;
    }
    
    template<bool sameTypes, typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<(is_vector<T>::value, is_shared_ptr<typename T::value_type>::value 
&& is_class<remove_cvref_t<typename T::value_type_element_type>>::value 
&& !sameTypes), 
typename std::vector<typename T::value_type::element_type>>
    transform(T val)
    {
        std::vector<T::value_type::element_type> t;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < val.size(); ++i)
        {
            typename T::value_type::element_type obj = *val[i];
            t.push_back(obj);
        }
        return t;
    }
```

Both these specialization are same and only differ on `sameTypes` boolean variable

This code currently errors out in call2 method while trying to using

```
std::get
auto ret = transform_back<std::get<I>(booltup)>(t); // error: I is not a compile time constant
```

How can you help?

1)What could be the work around to `std::get` issue here? Just cant figure out a way to fit in `std::size_t` as template arg here instead of function arg to make it work at compile time.
Other than this:

2)If you can suggest an alternative approach to implement from top level.

```
Args... params = CreateArgsInstanceFromTransformedArgs(targs);
```

That would be great. The path i took is not very convincing personally to me.

Comment: @G.Sliepen, I'd add _concrete but minimal nonetheless_.

Comment: @G.Sliepen I have edited to include code that i have so far while explitily stating further what do i need exactly. Sorry as it was unclear after the first edit.

Comment: @Enlico Edited. Apols if it was unclear after first edit

Comment: Do you really need to keep a list of which arguments you did transform? Why not have a back transformer that blindly converts all `std::unique_ptr<SomeClass>` to `SomeClass`, and `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SomeClass>>` to `std::vector<SomeClass>`? Because that would greatly simplify things.

Comment: @G.Sliepen
So imagine the original C++ function was foo(std::vector<shared_ptr<SomeClass>>);
I shouldn't be tranforming this targ in the first place because it is already in the format i need. So while tranforming back, this will become std::vector<SomeClass>, there would be no foo with that signature. 
In other words, if an targ[i] is a shared_ptr<SomeClass> or std::Container<shared_ptr<SomeClass>>, i wouldn't know if thats the original arg or result of my transformation.
So need something to keep that info, hence the boolean tuple

Comment: Maybe this is exactly what you need, but it really looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me. You end up having to store things in tuples, and transforming tuples is quite hard as you've already discovered. Do you really need to store all transformed arguments before you do something with it, and then transform them back, or can you transform, apply and transform back each argument individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you might do something like:

```
template <typename> struct Tag{};

std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> transform_to(Tag<std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>>, const SomeClass& s)
{
    return std::make_shared<SomeClass>(s);
}

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>> transform_to(Tag<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>>>, const std::vector<SomeClass>& v)
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>> res;
    res.reserve(v.size());
    for (const auto& s : v) {
        res.emplace_back(std::make_shared<SomeClass>(s));
    }
    return res;
}

const SomeClass& transform_to(Tag<SomeClass>, const std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>& s)
{
    return *s;
}

std::vector<SomeClass> transform_to(Tag<std::vector<SomeClass>>, const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>>& v)
{
    std::vector<SomeClass> res;
    res.reserve(v.size());
    for (const auto& s : v) {
        res.emplace_back(*s);
    }
    return res;
}

template <typename T>
const T& transform_to(Tag<T>, const T& t) { return t; } // No transformations
```

And then

```
std::function<void (Args...)> func;

template <typename ... transformed_args>
void operator () (transformed_args... targs) const
{
    func(transform_to(Tag<Args>(), targs)...);
}
```

Comment: I didn't know you could have two parameter packs expand at the same time... TIL!

Comment: @G.Sliepen: packs should be of the same size. That allows nice stuff :-)

Comment: Can you add an explanation why you have to use a tag class here, as opposed to using template specialization of `transform_to()`?

Comment: We might have `transform_to<Args>(targs)...` syntax, but partial specialization cannot be done on function (not needed here, but suppose a `std::set<T>` to `std::vector<T>` transformation), so it  would require another layer (partial specialization of class for example or `template <typename To, typename From> decltype(auto) transform_to(const From& from) { return transform_to(Tag<To>{}, from); }`).

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks I need something like this with an additional requirement that transform function also passes in or uses the information that whether Args...[i] and transformed_args...[i] are of same type or not. Reasons for that i have explained further in a comment i have added.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Yeah, that is a nice pack expansion property. I also trie to utilize here in my original code that i posted


auto ret1 = std::make_tuple<Args...>(call2(booltup, targs, N)...); // targs and N are expanded together so that i get indirect access to see the corresponding type in Args...

Comment: Apologies! i didn't read your solution with proper attention. It turns out this was exactly what i needed. So much more better than the path i was heading to. Great trick BTW, to an TMP noob like me this seems very close to magic. Really can't thank you enough @Jarod42 . Thanks again ! cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just explaining the use case here to add some context. Consider these three methods in C++ each represented with the function pointer `SomeTemplateClass::func`:

```
void foo(vector<shared_ptr<SomeClass>>)             // 1
// Args... = vector<shared_ptr<SomeClass>>, Targs... = vector<shared_ptr<SomeClass>>
void foo(vector<SomeClass>)                         // 2
// Args... = vector<SomeClass>, Targs... = vector<shared_ptr<SomeClass>>
void foo(vector<SomeClass>, vector<shared_ptr<SomeClass>>)  // 3
// Args... = vector<SomeClass>, vector<shared_ptr<SomeClass>>, Targs... = vector<shared_ptr<SomeClass>>, vector<shared_ptr<SomeClass>>
```

One instance each of `SomeTemplateClass` is exposed to Python via Pybind. I do these transformations so that when `foo` is called from Python, any arg `vector<T>(in C++)` is received as `vector<shared_ptr<T>>` in `SomeTemplateClass` functor. This helps in to get handle to previously created objects `T` that i need.

But as you can see from 3 cases for foo, `foo(vector<shared_ptr<T>>)` does not need to be transformed to and subsequently not need to be transformed back. The case of 'tranform_to'is easily handled with template specialization, but while transforming back, `vector<shared_ptr<T>>` cant be blindly converted back to `vector<T>`. So `(transform(targs...))` needs an additional logic to transform a particular arg (or targ) only when `targ[i]::type != arg[i]::type`

Building on Jarod's answer, i rather need something like this where in transform_to method for vector<shared_ptr> is further divided in two possible templates

```
template<bool wasOriginallyTransformed>
enable_if<!wasOriginallyTransformed, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>> transform_to(Tag<std::vector<SomeClass>>, const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>>& v)
{
    
    return v;
}

template<bool wasOriginallyTransformed>
enable_if<!wasOriginallyTransformed, std::vector<<SomeClass> 
transform_to(Tag<std::vector<SomeClass>>, const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>>& v)
{
     std::vector<SomeClass> res;
    res.reserve(v.size());
    for (const auto& s : v) {
        res.emplace_back(*s);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: As I understand `Args...` are the original values and you want `Args` -transform-> `TArgs` -transform_back-> `Args`, I do `SomeClass -> std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> -> SomeClass`, and `std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>-> std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> -> std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>`. I force tag to be the original value, I don't transform blindly `std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> -> SomeClass`.

Comment: Apologies! i didn't read your solution with proper attention. It turns out this was exactly what i needed. So much more better than the path i was heading to. Great trick BTW, to an TMP noob like me this seems very close to magic. Really can't thank you enough @Jarod42 . Thanks again ! cheers